# negative weight cycle detection in Bellman Ford's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

In the Bellman Ford's Algorithm for shortest path finding, how is the test "v.d > u.d + w(u,v)" detecting cycles of negative weight? Could someone explain it with an example?

Pseudocode:

[image]

Source: [https://www2.hawaii.edu/~suthers/courses/ics311f20/Notes/Topic-18.html](https://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Esuthers/courses/ics311f20/Notes/Topic-18.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider this graph where 1 is the starting vertex. After n-1=2 rounds of edge relaxations, shortest distances to each node is [0,-1,-2]. If the graph does not contain negative cycles, shortest distances must be finalised as there is no shortest path with length >= `n`. However, consider the edge (3,1) with weight -1. We can relax this edge one more time, even after the 2 rounds of relaxation. That means there is a shortest path with length `n`. That means there is a negative cycle.